# Is it possible to drown splicers in an airlock in BioShock 2?

Tags: bioshock-2

Having played BioShock 2 many, many times, there is still one stunt I haven't managed to pull off and I'm wondering if it is even possible.

Has anyone ever managed to get a splicer into an airlock with you and then cycle the airlock?

Multiple levels have airlocks that you can use more than once. There are two sets of them in the Fontaine Futuristics level, for example (from the Atlantic Express station to the "public" part of FF, and from there to the secret lab part of FF). It's possible to leave the secret lab portion and return to the public area, though for story purposes there is no real reason to do so. I've tried to get splicers to follow me into the secret lab airlock but could never get them to come all the way down the hall. That might just be a function of the leadhead splicer's AI though, since they are programmed to attack with ranged weapons and not to close the distance like a thuggish splicer would.

I usually don't bother to fully upgrade the Telekinesis plasmid (the difference between Telekensis 1 & 2 just doesn't seem to be worth the ADAM), so I wonder if I had Telekensis 3 might I be able to yank a splicer into the airlock?

Or is there some invisible wall that would prevent a splicer from entering an airlock? Big Daddies seem to be able to enter them, but they'll bludgeon your ass before you can cycle the airlock, and they shouldn't be able to drown anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Splicers are unable to be taken within an airlock, I have tried multiple times on different levels/area's:

- Siren alley
- Fontaine futuristic
- Atlantic express

There seems to be some kind of invisible barrier like you stated, once they reach it they seem to lose you as a target and will wonder back to where their AI paths start.